# Are there any Controls to show the nephogram?

Tags: .net, controls

[image: My nephogram]

I want to show the nephogram like the above which show the many-to-many relationships of objects.

Are there any free Controls? Or, maybe some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) for similar problems.

Graphviz can create an images similar to the one in your post which you can display to the user in a picturebox.